# VS Code http links not opening in web browser

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm running vscode in an Ubuntu LXC container with Ubuntu host.  Firefox is the default browser in the container.  However links in vscode (for example, Help...Documentation) don't work.  Nothing happens.

Perhaps there is a package I need to install?

Answer (score 5):

Figured it out.  Ran code --verbose and saw it was attempting an xdg-open.  Installed xdg-utils.  Viola!

Comment: Anyone with an idea for Windows? I suppose `xdg-utils` would be of little help here... Note: nothing written anywhere I can see (incl. the logs) on (Ctrl+) clicking links (with `--verbose`). Links are properly parsed + rendered, the tooltip for "Ctrl-Click" comes up etc., but then... nothing.